# QApplication in unicode

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

QApplication's constructor takes an (int argc, char**argv) to handle any Qt specific commandline arguments.

What if my app is in unicode? And I have a wchar_t** argv?

It seems a bit silly to create a char* copy of all the commandline args to pass to a library that is itself unicode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it would be.  If it wasn't for [this note](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qcoreapplication.html#arguments):

> Warning: On Unix, this list is built
> from the argc and argv parameters
> passed to the constructor in the
> main() function. The string-data in
> argv is interpreted using
> QString::fromLocal8Bit(); hence it is
> not possible to pass, for example,
> Japanese command line arguments on a
> system that runs in a Latin1 locale.
> Most modern Unix systems do not have
> this limitation, as they are
> Unicode-based.
>
> On NT-based Windows, this limitation
> does not apply either. On Windows, the
> arguments() are not built from the
> contents of argv/argc, as the content
> does not support Unicode. Instead, the
> arguments() are constructed from the
> return value of GetCommandLine(). As a
> result of this, the string given by
> arguments().at(0) might not be the
> program name on Windows, depending on
> how the application was started.

Admittedly, I don't get the word *either*.

Comment: Sounds like: Most Unix systems do not prevent you from using arguments from any language you want for this reason, and NT Windows systems don't prevent you either, but for a different reason.

Comment: So does that mean I can just pass the wchar version with a cast, or just ignore the args and pass NULL?

Comment: Just use `int main(int argc, char**argv)` and pass that. That works on both Unix and Windows (and OSX). Forget that `wmain` oddity.

Comment: Well, if you'd ignore the WinMain() oddity.  Too many programs already ignore the nShowCmd argument, what's another one.

Comment: I can't, Google now uses this post as the ranking hit.  It was rewritten, it now recommends that a program that targets Linux explicitly uses setlocale().

Comment: FWIW, the new link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments

Answer (score 0):

Well, `main` will always get `char** argv`, so that's what `QApplication` expects.  You can also convert them (using what locale/encoding?) to wide strings if you want to do other things with the command arguments.

Comment: Huh.  Didn't know about that -- because it's a Windows-only thing.  But then the function isn't `main` any more.

Comment: Solaris used to have a wmain - hadn't realized that Linux doesn't have unicode commandline.

Comment: Well, a UTF-8 locale (and therefore a UTF-8 command line) is becoming more and more common as a Linux default.  Which is Unicode and keeps things using `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Just link qtmain library.

qtmain is a helper library that enables the developer to write a cross-platform main() function on Windows. If you do not use qmake, qbs, or other build tools such as CMake, then you need to link against the qtmain library.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmain.html