# how can I get QT main function argv parameter as unicode encoding format

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, utf-8

I am new on QT and I have a problem with encoding. This is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    const char *charArray = "çşüğ";

    QStrıng str1(charArray);
    QString str2(argv[1]);
}
```

`argv[1]` value is the same with `charArray` on the caller exe side. But If I control the `str1` and `str2` values `str1` is looking *çşüğ* but `str2` ıs *.!?><*. I think it is because of encoding type. How can I fix this problem? Caller exe is c# application.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of ["QApplication in unicode"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072016/qapplication-in-unicode)

Comment: Using non-ASCII characters in a string literal is not a standard feature, so you can't know for sure what bytes actually end up in `charArray`.

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with C# directly, although that bit of information lets us know that this is specific to the Windows platform (though that should have been explicitly specified either in the question or the tags).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `QCoreApplication::arguments` For example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        QString str1 = "çşüğ";
        QString str2 = a.arguments().at(1);
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Note that in Windows environment Unicode refers to UTF-16 standard, you need wide char strings, example `const wchar_t *charArray = L"çşüğ";` While in Unix based environment Unicode refers to UTF-8.

Qt is supposed to be cross platform compatible so it tries to hide these differences through `QString` and other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
```

Then call [GetCommandLineW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: `GetCommandLineW` will return the program arguments as Unicode regardless of whether you use `main` or `wmain` or `WinMain`.

Comment: True, I guess I should have said "**OR** call GetCommandLineW."

Comment: @DanKorn It's not possible to use `wmain` here. [`QApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) class doesn't have constructor with `wchar_t**` parameter.

Comment: @Nikita: Those two statements are not causally linked.  It's true that QApplication doesn't have a constructor that takes a wchar_t**.  But that doesn't mean that you can't use wmain.

Comment: @DanKorn `QApplication` is used in context of this question, it's central part of QT application. So it's critical to construct proper `QApplication` instance, but it's not possible with `wchar_t**` parameter.

Comment: Yes, QApplication is a central part of a QT application, but its initialization does not seem to be pertinent to the original question here, which is "how can I get QT main function argv parameter as unicode."  If you use wmain, or call GetCommandLineW, then you will indeed get the main function argv parameters as Unicode, which, I submit, answers the question posed.