# pass unicode arguments to QApplication

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

I have windows console application which accepts unicode characters as argument

```
 wmain( int argc , wchar_t ** argv)
```

Now I want to pass the argv argument to my QApplication . However the QApplication accepts on char ** .

How do I manage to achieve this ?

Comment: Either, you use `main()` instead or you "translate" `wchar_t`s to `char`s. I cannot imagine that `QApplication` expects command line arguments where non-ASCII values are relevant but actually I'm not sure. File paths would be the exception.

Comment: IIRC `QApplication::arguments` on Windows is already Unicode-aware. Write portable code, using `int main(int argc, char**argv)` and Qt will magically make it work.

Comment: according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072141/2303202) the constructor argumenrt are not used to construct `QApplication::arguments()`. So you could as well not bother.

Answer (score 1):

Until [QTBUG-3200](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3200) is fixed, the only way to not be bounded by the "Current locale for non-Unicode" charset seem to convert the arguments to UTF-8, then

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf-8"));
QApplication(argc, argv_converted);
```

I cannot verify currently that it would work, though.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to pass these arguments to `QApplication` constructor. You can pass a dummy array, since it’s not used on Windows. The C-style program argument passing via `main` arguments is not the Windows-native way of accessing arguments, and `QApplication` doesn’t use it. The `wchar`-based `main` is a kludge that attempts to distract from the fact that `argv` is not a native interface.

This works:

```
int argcc = 1;
char arg0[1] = "";
char *argvc[2] = {&arg0, nullptr};
QApplication app(argcc, argvc);
```

Answer (score -1):

Qt do not use wchar_t* for Unicode strings as usual. Only QString or char*. If you want to contvert QString -> char* (or char* -> QString) use [QTextCodec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html). 
For example, older versions of Windows has encoding `cp866` for console and if you want send unicode QString into command line:

```
QString string = "Unicode text";
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("cp866");
QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode(string);
//encodedString.data() - char* representation of unicode QString
```

For reading input parameters in `main()` convert like this:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("cp866");
QString strArg = codec->toUnicode(argv);
```

Comment: I think you should mention `QChar*`, which is the direct Qt alternative to `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Also note that code page 866 is Cyrillic; it's the default on a very small number of PC's worldwide.